# Recursive Add method for BST using Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, recursion, binary-search-tree

Below is the implementation of a BST with an insertion function for it. currently, the code wouldn't work; It would just spit out `Tree { root: null }`

When i tried to debug it, it seems that it successfully adds the new Node to the correct spot, but once it returns from the function, all that data is lost and it ends up not inserting anything.

here is the code:

```js
class Node {
    constructor(value) {
        this.value = value
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;
    }
}

class Tree {
    constructor() {
        this.root = null
    }

    insert(value) {
        const insertHelper = (value, node) => {
            if (node === null) {
                node = new Node(value)
                return null
            } else if (node.value === node.value) {
                console.log("Value exists.")
                return null;
            } else if (node.value < node.value) {
                return this.insertHelper(node, node.right)
            } else {
                return this.insertHelper(node, node.left)
            }
        }

        return insertHelper(value, this.root)
    }

}

var tree = new Tree;
tree.insert(10)
tree.insert(5)

console.log(tree);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several issues:

- `this.root` is never modified. Function arguments are passed by value, so if you pass `this.root` as argument, and the function assigns a new value to the corresponding parameter variable `node`, this will *not* affect `this.root`. The solution is to let the helper function *return* the new value of the node that is passed as argument, so you can assign it back to the root (or other node).
- At several places you compare `node.value` with `node.value`. That is a mistake. The comparison should involve `value`.
- The recursive calls pass `node` as first argument, while the function expects the *value* as first argument.

Here is the corrected code:

```js
class Node {
    constructor(value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;
    }
}

class Tree {
    constructor() {
        this.root = null;
    }

    insert(value) {
        const insertHelper = (value, node) => {
            if (node === null) {
                node = new Node(value);
            } else if (node.value === value) {
                console.log("Value exists.");
            } else if (node.value < value) {
                node.right = insertHelper(value, node.right);
            } else {
                node.left = insertHelper(value, node.left);
            }
            return node;
        }
        this.root = insertHelper(value, this.root);
    }
}

var tree = new Tree;
tree.insert(10);
tree.insert(5);
console.log(tree);
```

NB: use semi-colons explicitly. Relying on the [automatic semi-colon insertion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Automatic_semicolon_insertion) is asking for [trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444080/do-you-recommend-using-semicolons-after-every-statement-in-javascript). One day it will hit you.