# Why this ternary operator not working? (more below)

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a function, which works fine with if/else, but not with ternary. Anyone knows the reason?
Also, if anyone could tell me a way the make it look nicer I'd really appreciate it.

```
function print(){
    for (const book of myLibrary){
        let cover = document.createElement('div')
        cover.textContent =`title: ${book.title} 
                            author: ${book.author}
                            pages: ${book.pages}` 
        
        // this line: (book.finished) ? cover.classList.add('bookStyle') : cover.classList.add('bookStyle2');
        
        if (book.finished){
            cover.classList.add('bookStyle')
        }
        else{
            cover.classList.add('bookStyle2')
        }

        books.appendChild(cover)
    }
}
```

Comment: "_if anyone could tell me a way the make it look nicer_" I'd start by not using a ternary. It is generally used to return a value depending on a condition. You're not doing anything with the return value. IMO it only makes things harder to read.

Comment: [Add semicolons after your statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444080/do-you-recommend-using-semicolons-after-every-statement-in-javascript). Your `(book.finished)` is interpreted as if you try to invoke a function on the template literal before it.

Comment: @Ivar The return value would be used if the ternary looked like `cover.classList.add(book.finished ? "bookStyle" : "bookStyle2")`.

Comment: See [What are the rules for JavaScript's automatic semicolon insertion (ASI)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2846283/4642212).

Comment: This might work
`((book.finished) ? cover.classList.add('bookStyle') : cover.classList.add('bookStyle2'))`

Answer (score 1):

Ternaries are great when they are used to return values, not perform or invoke actions.

Here is how I would improve your ternary.

```
// Old
this line: (book.finished) ? cover.classList.add('bookStyle') : cover.classList.add('bookStyle2');
// Prefered
cover.classList.add(book.finished ? 'bookStyle' : 'bookStyle2');
```