# Can't alter cells outside of the first column of a Google Sheet using getRange and setValue

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I just want to change a cell in `E5` but I can only seem to edit the first column.

```
var cell = sheet.getRange(2,5)
    cell.setValue("TEXT");
```

All this does is put "TEXT" into cell `E2`.

**EDIT: Below is the entire code.**

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SheetID").getSheetByName('Sheet1');

function doGet(e) {
  
  var amount = JSON.parse(e.parameter.amount)

  var student = JSON.parse(e.parameter.student)

var cell = sheet.getRange(student,2)

cell.setValue(amount);
}
```

**SAMPLE URL**
https://script.google.com/macros/s/mygooglesheetID/exec?amount=6&student=6

Comment: If your script is really adding `TEXT` TO A2 then the code included in the question is not the one that does that. If the current answer doesn't help please add a [mcve].

Comment: Ok, I've edited my post to include all code.

Comment: Please add the a sample URL showing the parameter values that are sent in your tests.

Comment: have you tried using A1notation on getRange() to make sure that everytime you setValue(), it always goes to the first column?

Comment: I've tried to use A1 notation but couldn't figure it out. I tried:                                    
var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("A1:H8");
var values = range.getValues();
values[6][3] = "This is D7";
values[5][6] = "This is G6";
range.setValues(values);

Answer (score 1):

The code in the question should is adding `TEXT` to `E2` but you want to be added to `E5`.

The first parameter is the row, the second is the column, so in order to get `E5`

**instead of**

```
var cell = sheet.getRange(2,5)
```

**use**

```
var cell = sheet.getRange(5,5);
```

Regarding the full code

**instead of**

```
var cell = sheet.getRange(student,2)
```

**use**

```
var cell = sheet.getRange(student,5)
```

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column

NOTE: As a good practice, include a semicolon (`;`) at the end of the JavaScript statements.

- [Do you recommend using semicolons after every statement in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/444080/1595451)

Comment: Even when I use (2,5), the "TEXT" appears in the first column. So regardless, it's still not getting out of the 1st column.

Comment: I didn't suggested to use `(2,5)`. Please read carefully my answer.

Comment: I don’t think you read my initial post correctly or maybe I was unclear. My original code SHOULD put TEXT into E2, but INSTEAD it puts it into A2.

Comment: Edited your question to replace `B5` by `E5` and `A2` by `E2` and edited my answer accordingly. If the changes to the question doesn't reflect what you are looking  please edit the question including a [mcve].