# Use rest operator feature of ES6+ to accept numbers from the user and calculate its sum

Tags: ecmascript-6, sum, numbers

I am looking at this exercise:

> #### 1. es6-sum-numbers
>
> You need to define a function which will add numbers and return the sum.
> Use rest operator feature of ES6+ to accept numbers from the user and calculate its sum.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> sum(1) // 1
> sum(1,2) // 3
> sum(1,2,4) // 7
> sum(1,2,3,4,5,6,7) // 28
> ```

The template code to work from is given as follows:

> ```
> const sum = () => {
>
> }
> module.exports = {sum}
> ```

What is the correct way to solve this exercise, I'm new to es6 and I can't understand?

Answer (score 0):

The "rest operator" that the challenge speaks of is a misnomer. This is not an operator. It is a specific syntax that can be used when declaring a function parameter list. Mozilla Contributors have an article on this syntax, called [rest parameter syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters):

> The rest parameter syntax allows a function to accept an indefinite number of arguments as an array, providing a way to represent [variadic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) in JavaScript.

The article continues with an example, that is **exactly** the function you are asked to provide (how lucky can you be, huh?):

> ```
> function sum(...theArgs) {
>   let total = 0;
>   for (const arg of theArgs) {
>     total += arg;
>   }
>   return total;
> }
>
> console.log(sum(1, 2, 3));
> // expected output: 6
>
> console.log(sum(1, 2, 3, 4));
> // expected output: 10
> ```

The above function definition can replace the placeholder (but don't touch the `module.exports` line). Or with arrow syntax (as used in the template):

```
const sum = (...theArgs) => {
  let total = 0;
  for (const arg of theArgs) {
    total += arg;
  }
  return total;
};

module.exports = {sum};
```

The template code you got to start with also promotes a bad habit: to drop the `;` statement separators and count on the automatic semicolon insertion algorithm. Don't go with that. [Type the semicolons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444080/do-you-recommend-using-semicolons-after-every-statement-in-javascript).