# One object , two methods

Tags: javascript

I try to understand why this works

// .......................................................

```
var hero = { 
  name: 'Joni', 
  type: 'blond',
  sayName: function() { 
    return this.name; 
  } 

  sayType: function() { 
    return this.type; } 
} 
document.write( hero.sayName()+ "</br>"); 
document.write( hero.sayType());
```

// .......................................................

but this doesn't works

// .......................................................

```
var hero = { 
  name: 'Joni', 
  type: 'blond',
  sayName: function() { 
    return this.name; 
  } 

  sayType: function() { 
    return this.type; 
    } 
} 
document.write( hero.sayName()+ "</br>"); 
document.write( hero.sayType());
```

// .......................................................

thanks

Comment: What doesn't work exactly, and where is the difference between the two code blocks?

Comment: Kill me, but where is the difference?

Comment: it shouldn't work on both because of a missing comma.

Comment: also, there's a comma missing after the sayName property.

Comment: Please post your actual code. Both examples contain errors and should not work.

Comment: @jAndy is correct, I added the [comma here](http://jsfiddle.net/erick/NSy2E/)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a semi-colon at the end of the "var hero" statement.  You are also missing some other commas.

```
var hero = { 
  name: 'Joni', 
  type: 'blond',
  sayName: function() { 
    return this.name; 
  }, // <<--- You missed the comma here

  sayType: function() { 
    return this.type; 
    } 
};  // <<--- You missed the semi colon!
document.write( hero.sayName()+ "</br>"); 
document.write( hero.sayType());
```

Going forward, you can completely avoid these issues by just running your code through JSLINT.  Goto jslint.com, paste your code, and you'll see the answers revealed to you.//

Comment: The semi colon isn't required in this instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42247/are-semicolons-needed-after-an-object-literal-assignment-in-javascript/42252#42252

Comment: @aiham.  It might not be "required", but you are relying on javascript's semi-colon insertion.  Which, if you read Crawford's book, you'll learn is a bad thing and can't always be relied on.
On my team, you wouldn't be allowed to check this in.

Comment: I wouldn't do it either, but it's not what was giving the error.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is in the enter before the saytype function in the second block. Besides the comma i see no reason why it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a comma after the sayName function. I couldn't see a difference between the two blocks of code, other than a new line character (Which doesn't make a difference). Both blocks of code were missing this comma.

```
var hero = { 
  name: 'Joni', 
  type: 'blond',
  sayName: function() { 
    return this.name; 
  },// <---  Missing Comma

  sayType: function() { 
    return this.type; 
    } 
} 
document.write( hero.sayName()+ "</br>"); 
document.write( hero.sayType());
```